# Adding Two Arrays Yields Unstable Return

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have created a script to add two arrays which is presented below. When the code below is executed it does not produce consistent results. Every time the script is executed I receive different answers. I am curious to determine what could be the cause of such a result.

```
//
//  main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int *AddArrays(int *A, int *B, int a, int b);

int main(void)

{
    int A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int B[7] = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;
    int c = a + b;
    int x = 0;
    int NewArray[c], *ArrayPtr;
    
    ArrayPtr = AddArrays(A,B,a,b);

    for( x = 0; x < c; x++)
    {
        *(NewArray + x) = *ArrayPtr;
        
        printf("Value of NewArray[%d] = %d\n", x, *(NewArray+x));
        sleep(1);
        
        ArrayPtr++;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}

int *AddArrays(int *A, int *B, int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    int d;
    int NewArray[a+b];
    
    for (c = 0; c < a; c++)
    {
        NewArray[c] = *A;
        A++;
        
    }
    
    for (d = 0; c < d; d++)
    {
        NewArray[a] = *B;
        a++;
        B++;
    }
    
    return NewArray;
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you ran this code in your debugger?

Comment: It built successfully but the output did not print the Array "A" with "B" appended to it. Instead it prints "1", "2" and then random numbers and then "0"s for the last array cell values.

Comment: That is not the debugger output. Also note that this is no contest. There is no "need" for a _bonus question_. (if you think types are actually "weired", you should re-read the chapter about types and one about programming paradigms.

Comment: A debugger should not give "error messages". Note: to address a comment to another poster, you use the well known syntax `@name`. `"` will not notify that addressee. This is just no tutorial site, but a Q&A forum.

Comment: And I had a question. And someone gave me an answer.

Comment: Much easier that first try yourself. I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second loop in AddArray you want d < b instead of c < d. The second loop never executes as is because d starts at zero and c will always be greater than zero after the first loop.

Comment: thanks. I realized that i need to make the array static in the function but it won't let me since it is of variable length. I reran the program and changed the NewArray length to [12] in the function and made it static. The program executed well except the B was appended wrong. Your answer solves that problem, but still, I don't know how to make it static in the function.

Comment: Sorry, after compiling your code I'm realizing your issue is two fold. You're returning the local variable NewArray inside of AddArray, this is not guaranteed to be anything after NewArray executes which is why you're seeing weird output.  You should probably pass in a pointer to the final array you'd like to copy into in AddArray and write into that instead of having the function return anything.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. I'll try adding a pointer argument now.

Comment: @JCodder: If you return the pointer to a `static` local array, think of what happens if you call the function a second time, while still requiring the values from the first call.

Comment: Yea I was able to solve the problem by passing the new array pointer (declared outside the function) as an argument and using this pointer as the basis to appending values. The function now returns void since there is no need to return anything.

Comment: @JCodder: fair legal, and I might do the same if not on a PC. However, on a PC, `malloc()` would be easier, more straight-forward and more universal. Just think if you called that function not from `main()`, but from another function, called from `main()`. You would have to pass the pointer all way down. Impractial for a normal program.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a reason to use `malloc`.

This statement:

```
return NewArray;
```

returns a pointer to the first element of the array. But you declared the array on the stack (i.e. not dynamically, without `malloc`), so as soon as control passes out of the function, the array passes out of scope and is no longer safe to use. Your use of it later causes *undefined behavior*, and you're lucky if all you get is random numbers.

Making `NewArray` static is not a good solution. For one thing, this means that you can use the function only once -- if you call it again, it will overwrite the array with the contents of its new arguments, and the results of the previous call will change in a way that you almost certainly don't intend.

You could also declare `NewArray` outside the function and pass in a pointer to it; the choice between the two designs depends on circumstances, but if you are trying to learn the language then I would advise you to try both.

Comment: Thanks! I did the second solution and it ended up working as per the other posters' suggestion. If I were to use malloc(), do I allocate space for the array inside the function? This would then also solve the problem and keep the array values safe from temporary local scope?

Comment: @JCodder: Yes, and yes. Don't forget that the code that calls `AddArrays` accepts responsibility for deleting the array when it is no longer needed. (This is a good practice, not a strict requirement of the language.) And for your "Bonus Question", look into *templates.*

Comment: @beta: "templates"? That is C, not C++.

Comment: @Olaf: Templates are legal in C++, and I'll be grateful if you show me a good way to do it in C++ without templates.

Comment: @Beta: Well, C and C++ are different languages. The question is about C, not C++. Your comment does imply there are templates in C. Possibly not a good idea to give a beginner (or other novice reader of your comment) who still figures out the basic features of C.

Comment: @Olaf: You're right, I failed to notice the C tag. JCodder, never mind what I said about the bonus question, my solution won't apply until/unless you move on to C++.

Comment: @Mets_CS11: I'll look at your other questions, but although I didn't downvote this one, I don't think I can upvote it; if you had reduced to a minimal complete example, you would have arrived at a very simple case of _problem returning a pointer to a variable,_ and if you type that phrase into Google you get the answer.

Comment: @Beta understood. I wrote that question 7 years ago when I was new to programming and a teen. I have now expanded my skills through college and then a few years in professional jobs. Unfortunately things like these prevents me from enjoying the full benefits of the site and the algorithm is very unforgiving.